# Comparar array en php

Tags: php, array

Tengo estos dos array que necesito comparar para borrar las diferencias.

Array1 que equivale a todo lo que hay en mysql

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 133
            [que] => Codigo
            [idcosa] => 9
            [1] => 36
            [2] => 40
            [3] => verde
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 134
            [que] => Codigo
            [idcosa] => 9
            [1] => 37
            [2] => 37
            [3] => borrar
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 135
            [que] => Codigo
            [idcosa] => 9
            [1] => 36
            [2] => 37
            [3] => colao
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 136
            [que] => Codigo
            [idcosa] => 9
            [1] => 36
            [2] => 70
            [3] => Gris marengo
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
        )

)
```

Array2 que equivale a lo que tengo de un producto cartesiano de un formulario

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 133
            [id] => 133
            [1] => 36
            [que] => Codigo
            [2] => 40
            [idcosa] => 9
            [3] => verde
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
            [12] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 135
            [id] => 135
            [1] => 36
            [que] => Codigo
            [2] => 37
            [idcosa] => 9
            [3] => colao
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
            [12] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 136
            [id] => 136
            [1] => 36
            [que] => Codigo
            [2] => 70
            [idcosa] => 9
            [3] => Gris marengo
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
            [12] => 
        )

)
```

Por lo que veo el producto cartesiano me mete un campo nuevo en el array que es [0] que tiene el mismo numero que [id]

si comparamos los datos me tendría que dar como resultado este:

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 134
        [que] => Codigo
        [idcosa] => 9
        [1] => 37
        [2] => 37
        [3] => borrar
        [4] => 
        [5] => 
        [6] => 
        [7] => 
        [8] => 
        [9] => 
        [10] => 
    )
```

Pero por alguna extraña razón no me lo da y me dice que el resultado de la comparativa es 0 o un código erróneo.

Estoy comparando con este codigo `$Diferencia = array_diff_assoc($array1,$array2);` y también he probado con array_diff a secas, mirando la web de php por si hay algún otro comparador no he visto nada mas ( bueno hay varios pero creo que no me encajan ) ¿hay alguna otra forma de hacer esto? o ¿tengo algo mal que no sepa?

El array_diff_assoc me lanza como resultado esto:

```
Array (
        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 136
                [que] => Codigo
                [idcosa] => 9
                [1] => 36
                [2] => 70
                [3] => Gris marengo
                [4] => 
                [5] => 
                [6] => 
                [7] => 
                [8] => 
                [9] => 
                [10] => 
            )

    )
```

Pero si os fijáis ese id esta tanto en el 1 como en el 2.
Posiblemente sea una tontería pero me lleva de cabeza y no lo veo, a ver si alguien que sepa mas que yo de php ve donde tengo el conflicto :) mil gracias a todos por adelantado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías usar [`array_udiff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php).

Así por ejemplo:

```
<?php

    $result = array_udiff($arr1, $arr2, function($a, $b) {

        // Si es igual
        if ($a['id'] == $b['id']) {
            return 0;
        }
        return -1;
    });

    print_r($result);
?>
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 134
            [que] => Codigo
            [idcosa] => 9
            [1] => 37
            [2] => 37
            [3] => borrar
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
        )

)
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/NBDP86077)

Comment: Genial, funciona perfecto :) mil gracias